# Cart Items Remove from opencart showing undefined

Tags: opencart, product, cart

[image] [image]

```
<div id="cart" class="top-cart">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-link btn-header btn-lg dropdown-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>Cart<span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php if ($products || $vouchers) { ?>
        <li>
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center"><?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
                <?php } ?></td>
              <td class="text-left"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
                <?php if ($product['option']) { ?>
                <?php $sum=0; foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
                <br />
                - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?> <?php echo $option['value']; ?>
                <?php $opprice = $option['price']; echo $opprice;  ?></small>
                <?php $sum += $option['price']; ?>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($product['recurring']) { ?>
                <br />
                - <small><?php echo $text_recurring; ?> <?php echo $product['recurring']; ?></small>
                <?php } ?></td>
              <td class="text-right">x <?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
              <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center"></td>
              <td class="text-left"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
              <td class="text-right">x&nbsp;1</td>
              <td class="text-right"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
              <td class="text-center text-danger"><button type="button" onclick="voucher.remove('<?php echo $voucher['key']; ?>');" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-right"><strong><?php echo $total['title']; ?></strong></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </table>
            <p class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> <?php echo $text_cart; ?></strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><strong><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <?php echo $text_checkout; ?></strong></a></p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li>
          <p class="text-center"><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

This is my cart page..When I am adding Items to fine working and When i trying to remove the Items from cart , its showing Undefined in the place of cart heading..

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-link btn-header btn-lg dropdown-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>Cart<span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button>
```

While removing items from Cart it showing undefined i need to show the default Cart only as per about button....

Comment: Please update your question with the error message shown.

Comment: its showing Undefined text in the place of Cart text

Comment: `<?php echo $text_cart; ?>` - here ?

Comment: <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-link btn-header btn-lg dropdown-toggle"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>Cart<span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button> check the button

Comment: Share the snap if possible.

Comment: I am also getting this problem but in a different way, when i click on remove button , the item is removed from the cart but header text doesn't automatically update. When i refresh page then header text is ok